# Remove red border on a field after using MVC unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to remove the red border on a field after validation. I still want that field to be validated but not have the red border around it. I want red border on the rest of the fields if the validation fails though.

I tried this and it did not remove the red border on that one field.

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        $(this).validate();

        $(".SomeClass").removeClass("input-validation-error");
        alert();
    });
});
```

I did not get any error messages. The alert displayed but the red border remained on that field.

Comment: It means that `.SomeClass` element is not the one with class `input-validation-error`. Post your HTML.

Comment: please use css inspector to see what classes are involved. There isn't enough information given for anyone to help you

Comment: I am not set on using the code I posted. If someone knows how to remove red border on one field but not the rest of the fields on validation, I would be happy.

Comment: From the code you posted its impossible to say, but check via inspector which class sets the red border, maybe it is .error?

Comment: input-validation-error is the class that sets red border. Isn't it done automatically with Jquery Validate or is it MVC? This is the field I am trying to remove red border on validation. @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeField, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "SomeClass" } })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I managed to fix the issue with css instead of jquery.

```
.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}


.SomeClass
{
    width : 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0 !important;

}
```

The !important is what did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Ive seen several stack overflow posts on people having issues with removeclass not working in various scenarios. I havent researched this in depth as to why this may be so Im just recommended an alternative option for you at this time.  I think toggleClass() may do the trick for you. Try togglecClass() instead of your remove method.

Comment: i believe you are targeting the correct class by the way. That is the class that creates the red border. So if you can just toggle it off it should disappear.

Comment: toggleClass did not work. Any other ideas? I am guessing that my function is running before the validation that is why it is not working.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could do it in css instead. For example adding a div around my field and do something like div .input-validation-error{ border : 0} Something like that. It did not work as well.